# Build failed after installing Cordova.plugins.diagnostic

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I added the [diagnostic plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic) to my cordova project and rebuild it, without chanching code. 
Then I got these erorors:

```
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1    App ERROR building one of the platforms    
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1    App MDAVSCLI
```

So I uninstalled it, but the errors still here...

So, my question, do you know where the errors come from, and why they are still here after removing the plugin?

Comment: try [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Comment: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered build errors and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. rsalva [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Comment: Hi, any news about this ?